# RAR Decompress on iPhone Device

Tags: iphone, zlib, rar, compression, libz

Has anyone found a solution to decompressing RAR files on iPhone (not Jailbroken)? It would be great if there was a library similar to libz.

I did not find anything official from RARlab.

Anyone successful with integrating [unRAR](http://wdtz.org/iphone/unrar/) into their app?  The
source code appears to be C++?

I know that this has been asked before, but I've not seen a solution other than porting unRAR which is beyond me. Would greatly appreciate any information or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: RARLab responded by saying they only offer UnRAR.dll for Windows and UnRAR source for Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the unRAR in an iOS app, you'll probably need to find someone experience with C++ to integrate it into your project.